# how to make non-root user to ssh using key instead of password?

Tags: ssh, nas, openssh, sshd, synology

I've recently purchased the Synology NAS 215j and having problems with SSH.

Root user works as expected I've added my public key to **/root/.ssh/authorized_keys**...

**Problems with non-root user:** 
sshd always asking the password and seems to ignore the key...
When I want to use public key authentication only I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

I've checked the permissions of user's home dir:

```
$ ll /volume1/homes/
drwx------    7 user001  users       4.0K Dec 16 22:55 user001/
drwx--x--x    5 admin      users       4.0K Dec 16 00:00 admin/
```

permissions of .ssh/*:

```
$ ll /volume1/homes/myuser001/.ssh
-rw-------    1 user001 users        725 Dec 16 11:23 authorized_keys

$ ll /volume1/homes/user1
drwx------    2 user001 users       4.0K Dec 16 15:52 .ssh/
```

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config:**

```
Ciphers blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com

Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel ERROR
LoginGraceTime 60

MaxStartups 2
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 3

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile    %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PermitRootLogin without-password
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 0
Banner /etc/ssh/issue.net
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
UseDNS no

ChrootDirectory none
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f DAEMON -u 000

Match User root
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Verbose output for non-root user logging attempt:

```
$ ssh user001@nas -p 22222 -vvv

OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to nas [192.168.1.51] port 22222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4 pat OpenSSH_6.5*,OpenSSH_6.6* compat 0x14000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to nas:22222 as 'skotik'
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: original KEX proposal: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: Compat: skipping algorithm "curve25519-sha256@libssh.org"
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: compat KEX proposal: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug3: put_host_port: [nas]:22222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [nas]:22222
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1022/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:SkJiuE7k6Z2ooVXv2cb4PGTeXgh+xNjxMtDG+8Pfqw0
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.1.51]:22222
debug3: put_host_port: [nas]:22222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [nas]:22222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.1.51]:22222
debug1: Host '[nas]:22222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug2: bits set: 1027/2048
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Connection refused
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7ff0b1c15460),
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug3: input_userauth_banner

DISCONNECT IMMIDIATELY IF YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED PERSON!

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Verbose output for successful root login (for comparison):

```
ssh -p 22222 root@nas -vvv                                                                          
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to nas [192.168.1.51] port 22222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4 pat OpenSSH_6.5*,OpenSSH_6.6* compat 0x14000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to nas:22222 as 'root'
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: original KEX proposal: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: Compat: skipping algorithm "curve25519-sha256@libssh.org"
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: compat KEX proposal: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug3: put_host_port: [nas]:22222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [nas]:22222
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 990/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:SkJiuE7k6Z2ooVXv2cb4PGTeXgh+xNjxMtDG+8Pfqw0
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.1.51]:22222
debug3: put_host_port: [nas]:22222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [nas]:22222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.1.51]:22222
debug1: Host '[nas]:22222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user001/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug2: bits set: 1035/2048
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Connection refused
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fc653600860),
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug3: input_userauth_banner

DISCONNECT IMMIDIATELY IF YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED PERSON!

By accessing this system you agree that all your actions
will be monitored and logged.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:NWHiMGnH1Sz8K/cLRV9x493V6B6P8+oat6xtwFViZl4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:NWHiMGnH1Sz8K/cLRV9x493V6B6P8+oat6xtwFViZl4
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/user001/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to nas ([192.168.1.51]:22222).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/X11R6/bin/xauth  list /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.6o3kYLK89Z/org.macosforge.xquartz:0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 87380
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Please help! I've spent 3 days googling and didn't find any solution why the same settings work for root user and don't work for regular user...
I'm in dispare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've contacted the Synology Support and they told me that this is going to be changed in DSMv6. And finally it was!